# The coefficient of the measure in 2d Euclidean space under coordinate transformation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, coordinate-systems, conformal-field-theory

On 2d Euclidean space with coordinate ($\sigma^1 , \sigma^2$), do a coordinate transformation:$$z = \sigma^1+i\sigma^2 \quad,\quad\bar z = \sigma^1-i\sigma^2$$
In the new coordinate $(z,\bar z)$, we can get the metric:$$g_{z\bar z} = g_{\bar z z} = \frac{1}{2}\quad,\quad g_{zz} = g_{\bar z\bar z} = 0$$
Then by the invariant volume element$\sqrt{|g|}d^dx$:$$dzd\bar z = 2d\sigma^1d\sigma^2$$
If we calculate the Jacobian of this coordinate transformation:$$J = \left |\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & i\\
1& -i
\end{array}\right| = -2i$$
Then we have $$dzd\bar z = -2i d\sigma^1d\sigma^2$$which is different from the result before. I know we can define the measure arbitarily so the coefficient can be absorbed into the re-definition of the measure. But I am wondering if there is any reason of this difference?

Comment: Not specifically related to the question, but let me stress that what you are doing is not a coordinate transformation in the strict sense, it is more a map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{C}$. Not sure, but this could also explain your problem: while the Jacobian computation should work fine anyway, maybe your formula for the invariant volume element silently assumes a real framework.

Comment: @FabioDiNoceraThanks for comment! In my opinion, what I am doing is exactly a coordinate transformation at least in *physical sense*. Could you explain the *strict sense* more precisely? As for my question, just like your point, the invariant volume element I used above indeed ignored the orientation of the manifold because of the absolute value of the determinant of the metric($\sqrt{|g|}$). After including the effect of this, these two formulas will give same result.

Comment: What I mean is that, strictly speaking, in the context of vector spaces, a coordinate transformation is choosing a different basis in the same vector space. While here you are going from a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ to one in $\mathbb{C}$. Then even if you mean coordinate transformation in a more differential geometric fashion, still, in that context this strictly means choosing other maps to represent your manifold locally on $\mathbb{R}^n$, going to a complex coordinatization is a different thing, and simply obeys different (even if often completely analogous) rules.

Comment: @FabioDiNocera Thanks for reply! Your points do make sense. The problem here may actually related to this pseudo-coordinate transformation.

Answer (score 0):

These two are the same. The $\sqrt{|g|}$ in fact ignore the orientation of the manifold, so if we consider the orientation, it has to be$\sqrt{g} = \sqrt{-4} =  -2i$ , which gives the result of Jacobian.